# Evaluate given Series in Closed Form

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form

$$f_c(x)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{r}{r^2-c^2}x^r$$
I have tried developing relations between differentials but have been unable to totally reduce to a closed form solution. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is $c\notin\mathbb Z$?

Comment: No details are given regarding c, it is a rather old Math Methods textbook. I assumed c is real and simply not equal to r to avoid discontinuity

Comment: A possible approach is to integrate 

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty r x^{r \pm c -1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$\frac{2n}{n^2-c^2}=\frac1{n-c}-\frac1{n+c}$$

Thus, we are left with:

$$2f_c(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{x^n}{n-c}-\frac{x^n}{n+c}\right]$$

Now notice that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n-c}=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+1-c}=x\Phi^*(x,1,1-c)$$

Likewise,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+c}=x\Phi^*(x,1,1+c)$$

where we use the [LerchPhi function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).

---

Another approach could be to apply integration.  Notice that:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n-c}&=x^c\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-c}}{n-c}\\&=x^c\int_0^x\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{n-c-1}\ dt\\&=x^c\int_0^x\frac{t^{-c}}{1-t}\ dt\end{align}$$

Likewise,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+c}=x^{-c}\int_0^x\frac{t^c}{1-t}\ dt$$

Which gives

$$2f_c(x)=\int_0^x\frac{(x/t)^c-(t/x)^c}{1-t}\ dt$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Note that $\quad\dfrac r{r^2-c^2}=\dfrac12\dfrac1{r-c}+\dfrac12\dfrac1{r+c}$,  so you have to find closed forms for
$$\sum_{r\ge 1}\dfrac{x^r}{r-c}=x^c\sum_{r\ge 1}\dfrac{x^{r-c}}{r-c}\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{r\ge 1}\dfrac{x^r}{r+c}=x^{-c}\sum_{r\ge 1}\dfrac{x^{r+c}}{r+c}.$$
Now $\;\dfrac{x^{r+c}}{r+c}$ is the antiderivative of $\;x^{r+c-1}$. Thus the last sum is the antiderivative  of
$$ \sum_{r\ge 1}x^{r+c-1}=x^{c-1}\sum_{r\ge 1}x^{r}=x^{c}\frac1{1-x}, $$
and similarly for the other sum.

Comment: Note: I already took the liberty of writing this approach all the way through in the second half of my answer.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art: I guess we were answering simultaneously (although I'm not very fast at typing answers). Anyway it's fine, as you give more details than me. I only wanted a hint, so I removed details I had initially given.